# Text Widgets are disappering when releasing flutter applications without --obfuscate option

Tags: android, flutter, apk, splash-screen, release

I have a flutter application that works perfectly in debug mode

But when releasing the app it has some issue,

- if i use --obfuscate then it get stuck in the splash page ( currently i'm not overriding the default splash screen)
- if i don't use that option then the app launch normally except almost all Text Widgets like this image

[image]

I used flutter native splash before and i removed it later , i don't know if its a part of the problem

I also changed the signing key to new one

So I want to know why exactly this is happening and also why bottom navigation bar text is still showing
And how can i debug this in release mode

I have tried building in both debug and release modes and with/without obfuscating

Comment: Some code would be helpful ...